# Initializing statically sized arrays for types without a default constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, constructor, default-constructor

I'm coding up a simple templated circular buffer:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
class CircularBuffer {

    T      _buf[N];
    T     *_data;
    size_t _head;
    size_t _count;
    size_t _capacity;

    CircularBuffer():
            _data(nullptr),
            _head(0),
            _count(0),
            _capacity(N) {}

protected:

    T* buffer() {
        if (_count <= N) return &_buf;
        else return _data;
    }

public:

    T& operator[](size_t i) {
        size_t j = i % _count;
        j = (_head + j) % _capacity;
        return buffer()[j];
    }

    T& push_back(const T& o) {
        if (_count == _capacity) {
            dynamically_allocate_data();
        }
        size_t j = (_head + _count++) % _capcity;
        buffer()[j] = o;
    }

    T pop_front() {
        size_t old_head = _head;
        _head = (_head + 1) % _capacity;
        return buffer()[old_head];
    }

};
```

This is stripped down from the real thing, but it's not far off, and you get the idea. This avoids a memory allocation for buffers of less than `N` items.

The problem is that this doesn't work for `T` which do not have default constructors. I could provide a constructor for `CircularBuffer` -- ala `std::vector`'s-- which accepts a `T` with which to fill the empty buffer, but I am not sure how to actually implement this without still implicitly invoking `T`'s (possibly non-existent) default constructor.

Replies to similar questions suggest using `std::vector` or placement new on a `void*` array, but in this case that does not apply because the whole point is to avoid dynamically allocating memory in an inner loop.

How can I construct this class for `T` without default constructors? (Or alternatively, is there another scheme that would avoid the need for constructing blank `T` in the buffer to begin with?)

Comment: `placement new` do **not** allocate memory.

Comment: You could probably use [placement `new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new) in this role.

Comment: @appleapple How do I declare a static array of `void*`?

Comment: you can use `(unsigned) char[]`

Comment: You want `std::aligned_storage` and placement new.

Comment: @NathanOliver I think that's what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `std::optional` (or `boost::optional` if your compiler is pre-17)? You could define the static array as `std::optional<T> _buf[N];`.

The `std::optional` type supports placement construction (so `T` doesn't need a default constructor) and allocates statically, so that would answer your requirements, wouldn't it?